# I'm having trouble writing to System32 on a 64-bit PC with a 32-bit-ONLY class library?

Tags: system32

The Problem:

Environment: Using Visual Studio in Windows, most any version since the 2000's.

Pain point: I have a DLL class library in 32-bit-preferred project and I can't see or write to the necessary files in System32.

Comment: If you are posting a solution to a problem, you should create the question outlining the problem and a separate answer outlining the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution:

Explanation: System32 is a virtualized folder on a 64-bit machine. 32-bit applications are redirected to a different folder specifically geared towards the needs of 32-bit applications. I believe this folder is named WOW64. You need to stop the redirection in certain instances.

The Fix: Use Sysnative instead of System32!

Example: Trying to access c:\Windows\System32. Should use c:\Windows\Sysnative as your path instead!

Note: You will never be able to visit Sysnative in Windows Explorer. It simply tells Windows not to redirect to another folder. Buyer beware :)

If you need Admin rights, use an app. Manifest with admin or higher rights specified.